# How do I collect a single column in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to perform an action on a single column.
Unfortunately, after I transform that column, it is now no longer a part of the dataframe it came from but a Column object. As such, it cannot be collected.

Here is an example:

```py
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([Row(array=[1,2,3])])
df['array'].collect()
```

This produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

How can I use the `collect()` function on a single column?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Spark >= 2.0**

Starting from Spark 2.0.0 you need to explicitly specify `.rdd` in order to use `flatMap`

```
df.select("array").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
```

**Spark < 2.0**

Just `select` and `flatMap`:

```
df.select("array").flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
## [[1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: so using select instead of subsetting essentially turns this in to a one column dataframe instead of a Column

Comment: Thats right. `Column` is just a SQL DSL expression not a standalone data structure.

Comment: What is the equivalent in spark 2.0? I can't see flatMap as a method on DataFrame

Comment: @ThatDataGuy you need to explicitly pass `.rdd` now. Once it was wrapped in. e.g. `df.select("array").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()`

Comment: Converting a dataframe to rdd creates an overhead. Try avoiding it with something like
`data = list(map(lambda x: x[0], df.select("array").collect()))`
Flatten the list using normal python code